# How do I change values in my subarrays into the avarage of those values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, sub-array

I have an array:

```
> a

array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
```

I want to change those values to the avarage of those values, so the output will be:

```
> a

array([[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]])
```

Is there a fast way to do this without using a `for` loop?

Comment: So, you just want each row to be mean of that row?

Comment: Why do you need to replicate the means? In most cases, `a.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)` is sufficient without the need of duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to use `numpy` module the [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) functions are useful for this (Though they do this by highly optimized loops as well).

`a.mean(axis=1)` gets the row mean and `np.broadcast_to` broadcasts the result to the desired shape. `.T` just returns transpose of the result

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]])
np.broadcast_to(a.mean(axis=1), a.shape).T
```

Output:

```
array([[2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
n = a.shape[1]
np.repeat(a.mean(axis=1), n).reshape(-1, n)
```

Output:

```
array([[2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3.],
       [4., 4., 4.]])
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"... Is there a fast way to do this without using a `for` loop? ..."*

You can use a *[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)*.
Note, I'm using the *int* function here, since your provided data was non-fractional.

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
a = [([int(sum(x) / len(x))] * 3) for x in a]
```

Output

```
[[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```